# What does "throttle is staggered" mean?

Tags: jet, multi-engine

What does "throttle is staggered" mean? and how is it related to adjustment of MEC(Main Engine Control) in B737-300(CFM56-3C)?and which are safety issues regarding that?

Comment: You’ve asked 3 questions and given us very little to work with.  You’re rolling the dice that someone with a maintenance manual and very specific experience might jump in here, but you’d have a much better chance if you provided a full quote in context.  Then those with similar experience could at least stand some chance of deciphering a probable reason.

Comment: P.S.  “Staggered” just means the levers are not in the same position…

Comment: Michael, what is the risk of throttle stagger?

Comment: Where does your information about the term "throttle stagger" come from? I mean, did you hear it in a movie, read it in a flight manual, or what?

Comment: Saeed, per my first comment, tedder42's comment, and John K's answer, you need to explain where the term comes from!  If John's interpretation is correct and it comes from a pilot gripe then I don't see any real risk, it's more of an annoyance that they don't match.  But please clarify your question so we don't play these guessing games, and if you are in a position to fix the aircraft then by all means **you need to get absolutely clear with the pilot and other maintenance personnel on both the meaning of the gripe and corrective action!!!**  Don't fix airplanes off random internet advice.

Answer (score 2):

If I was a mechanic looking at that snag, I would assume the  pilot is complaining the two thrust levers are way out of alignment when engine N1s are matched. They are usually never 100% perfectly aligned, but most pilots will start to complain if the stagger is more than, say, a quarter of the width of the lever handles.

This makes setting power a pain in the butt, and can be an issue in an abnormal procedure when you have to set go around thrust on a missed approach, and more care and tweaking is required by the pilot setting thrust. Basically, higher workload in abnormal situations is the risk factor.

The engine being non-FADEC, there is a need to check the rigging/adjustment between the thrust levers and the fuel control system, or within the fuel control system itself.

Comment: Does "snag" have the same meaning as "gripe" or "squawk"?  (pilot initiated maintenance action request)  I haven't heard that term before...

Comment: Yes.  Maybe a Canadian thing? I assumed it was common term in US as well.